# when button click to activated mouse scroll in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, motionevent

After button click to  mouse scroll to be activted,then scroll up to value increment and scroll down  to value decrement.Button inside code here not working, my sample code here,please analysis code to help me.

```
enter code here
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button;
int x,f;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);          
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {           
        @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                if (event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL) < 0.0f)
                    //selectNext();
                {
                    x=Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());
                    f=x+5;
                    button.setText(""+f); 
                }
                else
                {
                    x=Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());
                    f=x-5;
                    button.setText(""+f);  
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }           
    });
```

}

Comment: mouse scroll??? any mouse available in android?

Comment: yes mouse scroll work,but i need button touch to mouse scroll up to value increment and scroll down to value decrement ,is it possible or not,my code analysis to edit code please help me.

Comment: question related example  send me please..

Comment: button click to  setOnGenericMotionListener event using mouse cursor work any place with mouse scroll up and down changed to button value,please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a **ScrollView** as your layout in your UI.

With this layout you can program your button to handle the click and use the **ScrollView.scrollBy(x,y)** function to do the necessary.